# What does this function table mean?

Tags: datasheet, boolean-algebra, logic-level, decoder

This table, part of the [SN74LS138 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/sn74ls138), explains how inputs relate to outputs:

[image: SN74S138A function table]

However, I'm no electrical engineer and I don't understand the bit I've circled in red which says \$\small\mathrm{\overline G2=\overline G2A +\overline G2B}\$.

I don't even know what to call those overlined characters, so I'm stumped on how to search for the meaning of this.

I *do* know that the chip has inputs `G1`, `G2A`, and `G2B`. In my case two of the inputs are even hardwired to fixed values: `G1` is high and `G2B` is low, so it's really only `G2A` that I need/get to control.

**Question:**
If I'm interested in the yellow cell I've highlighted in the image above, I know how to monitor output `Y2`, but **should I set `G2A` low or high?** I suppose it should be set to the opposite state when I'm checking the other 138s that cover other parts of the keyboard.

**Bonus question:**
What is the name of these overlined characters, and what is the idea behind its usage?

**Super duper bonus question:**
Isn't this backwards? Why are all the outputs except one set high? I would've expected the "chosen" pin to be the only one set high, with all the others set low. This way (in a keyboard matrix), all return lines will be high *except* for the one with the keypress in it. Why isn't the default state low?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data sheet describes G1, G2A and G2B as the enable inputs.  G1 is described as active-high, and G2A and G2B are active-low.  It is common to designate active-low signals by a bar over the signal name.  See also [Convention for inverted signal](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/468559/convention-for-inverted-signal).

In the equation, [the `+` sign is the logical OR operator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/131317/why-is-the-sign-commonly-used-as-logic-or-operator).  This means that G2 will be H if either G2A or G2B is H.  If both G2A and G2B are L, then G2 will be L.

To get Y2 to be L, you must set G1 to be H and both G2A and G2B to be L.  Since you said G1 is hardwired to H and G2B is hardwired to L, you simply need to set G2B to L.

> Why are all the outputs except one set high?

The data sheet says:

> Two active-low and one active-high enable inputs reduce the need for
> external gates or inverters when expanding.

Comment: Adding to this, the reason all outputs except one are high is that this is simply how that chip works - if you need it the other way round, you need to use the 74...238.